# Kendo UI Grid Hierarchy Invalid Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo Grid and I'm trying to implement the Hierarchy like in the example on the [demo portion of their web site](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html).

It all works except for the `.Name("WorkOrderGrid_#=Event.EventReliabilityKey#")` line.  If I give it just a regular string like `.Name("WorkOrderGrid")` then it works fine except that it has to be a unique name otherwise all results display in the first hierarchy dropdown area.  It has to be something strange with the `.Name()` becuase, as you can see further down, I'm using the template syntax successfully in my `.Read()` line.

Here is my template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="currentWorkTemplateGrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Reliability.BusinessLogic.Models.FloorTourDownEventsModel>()
        .Name("WorkOrderGrid_#=Event.EventReliabilityKey#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.WorkOrderID).Title("Work Order");
            columns.Bound(c => c.WorkOrderDesc).Title("Description");
            columns.Bound(c => c.VarianceDur).Title("Variance");
            columns.Bound(c => c.PlanDur).Title("PlanDur");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DO_ShopComment).Title("Comments");
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetCurrentWorkOrders", "FloorTour", new { eventKey = "#=Event.EventReliabilityKey#", eventStart = DateTime.Today, eventEnd = DateTime.Today }))
        )
        .Sortable()
        .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
```

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  I'm not sure why this is but it turns out that the `name()` string needs to be `.Name("WorkOrderGrid_#=EventReliabilityKey#")`.  It cannot have the `.` to traverse the object.  Once I changed my `FloorTourDownEventsModel` model to have the `EventReliabilityKey` on the first level, the grid template worked.  :/

Comment: I am working with the Hierarchy demo as well for Kendo Grid and am stuck creating a template button inside the sub grid where I want to read the value from the parent grid. Can you help? My question is listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417604/kendo-grid-hierarchy-passing-id-from-master-grid)